# Excel VBA AutoFill method of Range class failed - failure when only one record is present

Tags: excel, vba

I put together a spreadsheet that imports two files, compares them, and outputs the discrepancies. It has been working perfectly fine until someone tried to use it with a file that only had one record to check. When they ran the macro, it produced the AutoFill method of Range class failed error. This seems to be affecting only single row instances and I am unable to troubleshoot. Below is the portion of the code that specifically performs the data checks producing the error. I'm sure it's something super simple I have overlooked. I hope someone can see it.

```
Sub AddDataChecks(numCols, startingCol, Lrow)
  
    otherCol = numCols + numCols + 2
  
    
    Cells(2, startingCol).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC" & numCols + 2 & "=0,FALSE,IF(R1C[-" & numCols & "]=""SSN"",TRUE,RC[-" & numCols & "]=RC[-" & otherCol & "]))"
    
  If Lrow > 2 Then
            Cells(2, startingCol).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, startingCol), Cells(Lrow, startingCol))
  End If
        
   Range(Cells(2, startingCol), Cells(Lrow, startingCol + numCols - 1)).Select
   

    Selection.FillRight
    
    
    Cells(2, startingCol + numCols).Select
    
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(RC[-" & numCols & "]:RC[-1],FALSE)"
    
    Error starts here >>>Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, startingCol + numCols), Cells(Lrow, startingCol + numCols))
    
    Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(Lrow, numCols)).Select
```

Comment: I suppose that `Lrow` means the last row. If my supposition is correct and only a row exists, then for `Destination:=Range(Cells(2, startingCol + numCols), Cells(Lrow, startingCol + numCols))` there is no range to be filled. `Selection` is the destination itself in terms of rows...

Comment: @FaneDuru you are correct, Lrow means the last row. In this instance when only one record is present, Lrow is equal to 2. I added an If statement to run the line that has been erroring out only if Lrow is > 2. This seems to have worked. Of course it was obvious - thank you!